# Unable to install Tesseract 5.0 version on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to run Tesseract 4.0 or Tesseract 5.0 on my AWS Lambda function. So I have my docker file like so-

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

RUN mkdir app

# Copy function code
COPY / ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/app


# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install tesseract

RUN yum install -y poppler-utils

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.com.emlAndMsgParser.mail_parser_test.getEmail_from_msg" ]
```

but when i do DockerBuild-"docker build -t qa-lambda ." on my terminal, it says Tesseract 3.0 version is getting installed. When i deploy this built Docker image to AWS Lambda,it also says Tesseract 3.0 is installed.
But I want Tesseract 4.0 or preferably Tesserct 5.0.
I tried changing the "**RUN yum -y install tesseract**" in my Dockerfile to "**RUN yum -y install tesseract 5.0.0-alpha-320-g8dc3**" and "**RUN yum -y install tesseract -y**" or "**RUN yum -y install tesseract***".
But all of them are installing Tesseract 3.0.
Please can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
I am a bit new to Tesseract, so any help is appreciated..thanks!

Comment: There is no `tesseract 5.0.0` package for amazon linux 2. You have to compile it yourself.

Comment: Um.. how to compile it myserlf? Please can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Having the same problem, I finally created a `Dockerfile` myself:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:11 q

# Prepare dev tools
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install wget libstdc++ autoconf automake libtool autoconf-archive pkg-config gcc gcc-c++ make libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel zlib-devel
RUN yum group install -y "Development Tools"

# Build leptonica
WORKDIR /opt
RUN wget http://www.leptonica.org/source/leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz
RUN ls -la
RUN tar -zxvf leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz
WORKDIR ./leptonica-1.82.0
RUN ./configure
RUN make -j
RUN make install
RUN cd .. && rm leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz

# Build tesseract
RUN wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/refs/tags/5.2.0.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxvf 5.2.0.tar.gz
WORKDIR ./tesseract-5.2.0
RUN ./autogen.sh
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include ./configure --with-extra-includes=/usr/local/include --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib
RUN LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" make -j
RUN make install
RUN /sbin/ldconfig
RUN cd .. && rm 5.2.0.tar.gz

# Optional: install language packs
RUN wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/deu.traineddata
RUN wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/eng.traineddata
RUN mv *.traineddata /usr/local/share/tessdata

WORKDIR /root

ENTRYPOINT [ "tesseract", "--version" ]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it works, just need to change the WORKDIR /root or else give proper permission otherwise it gives permission error in the lambda.

Comment: it works, I had to skip the step of 
``RUN LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include" make -j`` because it was failing with a lot of errors. And ``WORKDIR /var/task`` in the end to set ``CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]``.

Answer (score 1):

Nov 2023 - To reduce the size of your Docker image, Use a multi-stage build.

Similar to @GiehlMan.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10 as builder

# Prepare dev tools
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install wget libstdc++ autoconf automake libtool autoconf-archive pkg-config gcc gcc-c++ make libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel zlib-devel
RUN yum group install -y "Development Tools"

# Build leptonica
WORKDIR /opt
RUN wget http://www.leptonica.org/source/leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz
RUN ls -la
RUN tar -zxvf leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz
WORKDIR ./leptonica-1.82.0
RUN ./configure
RUN make -j
RUN make install
RUN cd .. && rm leptonica-1.82.0.tar.gz

# Build tesseract
RUN wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/refs/tags/5.2.0.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxvf 5.2.0.tar.gz
WORKDIR ./tesseract-5.2.0
RUN ./autogen.sh
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig LIBLEPT_HEADERSDIR=/usr/local/include ./configure --with-extra-includes=/usr/local/include --with-extra-libraries=/usr/local/lib
RUN make install
RUN /sbin/ldconfig
RUN cd .. && rm 5.2.0.tar.gz

# install language packs
RUN wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/eng.traineddata
RUN mv *.traineddata /usr/local/share/tessdata

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.10

# Copy necessary files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/bin/tesseract /usr/local/bin/tesseract
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/share/tessdata /usr/local/share/tessdata
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/libtesseract* /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/lib/liblept* /usr/local/lib/

# Additional dependencies for Tesseract
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib64/libjbig.so.2.0 /usr/lib64/libjbig.so.2.0
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.5 /usr/lib64/libtiff.so.5
COPY --from=builder /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1

ENV PATH="/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

RUN tesseract --version

# lambda handler
COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --upgrade pip wheel
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

COPY handler.py ./

CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```